# How do I resolve BSOD after installing Internet Explorer 11/Visual Studio 2013 Update 4?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, bsod, visual-studio-2013

This is Windows 7 64 installed as virtual machine using vmware. I get a BSOD after I install Internet Explorer 11.

I also get the same BSOD when I install Visual Studio 2013, update 4.  I can get into Windows when I select "Disable Driver Signature Enforcement" in advanced boot options.

The error says:

> STOP: c000021a {Fatal System Error}
>
> The Verification of a KnownDLL failed. system process terminated unexpectedly with a status of 0xc0000428 (0x00290ff0 0x00000000).
>
> The system has been shut down

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a Driver Signature Problem. So, how do we solve that?

We can get Technical and actually read the Crash Dumps.  That will tell us which file, but lets try something more basic.

We need to Verify System Files.  Much like a Virus Removal, some System files are changed / corrupted.  If an Update doesn't take, it will leave the OS in the same situation.

So, the test:

**Open Command Prompt as an Administrator and Type:**

**sfc /scannow**

(System File Checker)

This will scan all System Files and conclude whether or not they are corrupted.  Once it finishes doing that, it will attempt to repair the Corrupted Files.

So, go do that, and reply with what happens.